# Which test runner would be ideal to run webdriverjs test suite

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

As Angular team plans to stop development of Protractor soon, I am looking for alternatives for our protractor test suite. As we don't really use a lot of protractor specific stuff, i just looking to remove the wrapper around webdriver, and just use webdriverjs instead. Any suggestions for a test runner that i can use to run the protractor config file, which looks something like this.

```js
var { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {

    allScriptsTimeout: 40000,
    specs: [
        './src/tests/*/*.e2e-spec.ts',    
    ],

    
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
            args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=2880,2000', '--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser', '--disable-dev-shm-usage'],
            // args: ['--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser', '--window-size=2880,1800'],
// Set download path and avoid prompting for download even though
// this is already the default on Chrome but for completeness
            prefs: {
                'download': {
                    'prompt_for_download': false,
                    'directory_upgrade': true,
                    'default_directory': 'C:\\downloadtemp'
                }
            }
        }
    },

    directConnect: true,
    // Used for running against development server baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    // Used for running against an env - replaced now as jenkins job specifies the baseUrl as part of protractor command


    framework: 'jasmine',
    //to run the e2e tests,from the app root run the command ng e2e

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 240000,
        print: function () {
        }
    },
    onPrepare: function () {
        //browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

        require('ts-node').register({
            project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
        });
        //clear down the previous test run downloads
        var fs = require('fs');

        function rmDir(dirPath) {
            try {
                var files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);
            } catch (e) {
                return;
            }
            if (files.length > 0)
                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    var filePath = dirPath + '/' + files[i];
                    if (fs.statSync(filePath).isFile())
                        fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
                    else rmDir(filePath);
                }
            fs.rmdirSync(dirPath);
        }

        rmDir('C:\\downloadtemp');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: 'none' } }));

        var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            consolidateAll: true,
            savePath: 'testresults/xmltestresults',
            filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
        }));

        var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-beautiful-reporter');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({

            baseDirectory: 'testresults/htmltestreport',
            takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
            gatherBrowserLogs: true,
            docTitle: 'Freecon Test Report',
            preserveDirectory: false,
        }).getJasmine2Reporter());
    }
};
```

Comment: if you remove the wrapper you should end up having selenium webdriver with js binding. I recommend you to read this short thread https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/discussions/6963 it may be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have looked at moving to other frameworks like webdriver.io, cypress etc. But I just wanted to check which test runner works well if you just want to use webdriverjs. i have tried mocha n jest, which seems to work well, just i am having trouble running the config file against it.